# Question about the majorization of the Cauchy principal value

Tags: distribution-theory, cauchy-principal-value, majorization

I'm trying to understand a majorization that the professor has given of the Cauchy principal value.

The Cauchy principal value is a distribution defined as
$$ \left<v_p\left(\frac{1}{x}\right), \phi \right> = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{|x|\geq \epsilon} \frac{\phi(x)}{x}dx
$$

By the mean value theorem, we have

for $|x| \leq 1$: $$\left|\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}\right| \leq \left| \frac{\phi'(\xi)(x-0)}{x} \right| \leq \sup_{|x|\leq 1}{|\phi'(x)|}$$
and for $|x| \geq 1$: $$\left|\frac{\phi(x)}{x}\right| \leq \sup_{|x| \geq1}|\phi(x) | $$

Thus (and this is the part I don't understand)
$$
\left|\int_{|x|\geq \epsilon} \frac{\phi(x)}{x}\,dx\right|
\leq \int_{1 \geq |x| \geq \epsilon} \left|\frac{\phi(x) - \phi(0)}{x}\right| \,dx + \int_{R \geq |x| \geq 1} \left|\frac{\phi(x)}{x}\right|\,dx \leq 2 R \sup_{|x| \leq R}{\left(|\phi(x)| + |\phi'(x)|\right)}
$$
I don't understand why we have to multiply by $2R$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rough bound.

$$
\int_{R \geq |x| \geq 1} |\frac{\phi(x)}{x}|dx 
\leq 
\int_{R \geq |x| \geq 1} \sup |\phi| dx 
\leq
\sup |\phi|\int_{R \geq |x|} dx
= 2R \sup |\phi|.
$$

Comment: ok! but it's not the derivative of $\phi$, no?

Comment: Indeed. That's $\phi$ itself. Corrected.